# Unable to render Admin Notices

Tags: admin, wp-admin, dashboard, notices

I am trying to build a plugin and on activation I would like to render message on the dashboard whether the table exists or not but on activation I am getting the following error:

The plugin generated 48 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

My Code is :

```
function table_creation_success(){
    echo "<div class='updated'><p>Table Created!</p></div>";
}

function table_creation_failure(){ 
    echo "<div class='error'><p>Table Already Exists!</p></div>";
}


// Function to create the words table if it doesn't exist
function initiate_table_creation(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_screen;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "words" ;
    if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE $tablename") != $tablename ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'table_creation_success' );
    }else{
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'table_creation_failure' );
    }
    do_action( 'admin_notices' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'initiate_table_creation' );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In **wp-config.php** set the turn debugging on (search for `'DEBUG'` and set it's value to true).  That should then output the full error.

Comment: Although - if you are having to manually call `do_action('admin_notices')` it suggests that you are trying to output the notice in the wrong place (either to early or to late).  Do you absolutly have to only show the message on activation?  If no, you could do away with the activation function and just add the table check and relevant output in a function hooked to the `admin_notices` action.